# Multiple Definitions of Same #define Macro in Required Libraries

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-warnings, c-preprocessor

Two of the libraries I am including share the same definition of a macro in each of their respective .h files.

```
#define MAX <some value>       //first definition of MAX in a file
#define MAX <some other value> //second definition of MAX in a *different* file
```

and in compilation I get

```
.../httpd.h:43:1: warning: "MAX" redefined
```

and

```
.../opencv2/core/types_c.h:272:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
```

I've checked each of these headers, and they have the #include guards.

What is the best way to fix this error (failing that, suppress the warning with a different -W flag)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only bad part about this situation is dependencies on `MAX` in your code, if any.  If you don't have any, adding an `#undef MAX` between the two `#include`s is probably the fastest fix. If you *do* have dependencies on `MAX` you might need to figure out which one (I guess it's the last :-) and do something appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Neither include guards nor compiler flags will help you here.  You have approximately two possible solutions:

1. Don't `#include` both headers into the same source file.
2. Add an `#undef MAX` in-between the two `#include`s.

Comment: Third option being edit source (should not take too much time).
Also I'd complain at bugzilla/mailing list/support.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, Nick, I ended up fixing this by changing the source, as AoeAoe mentioned in a comment above.  Turns out that the only place httpd.h's `MAX()` and `MIN()` macros get used is in httpd.cpp, so I just moved those `#defines` into httpd.cpp, where they really should have been in the first place.

In fact, they may have been there in the original MJPG-Streamer code, and perhaps Robotis just mangled it when they picked out the pieces they wanted to use for the Darwin framework.  At any rate, the current MJPG-Streamer code has `#ifndef` guards around `MAX` and `MIN` and also has them in a separate `utils.h` file [here](http://mjpg-streamer.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer/utils.h?revision=117&view=markup) that just gets included in `httpd.c`, [here](http://mjpg-streamer.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer/plugins/output_http/httpd.c?revision=160&view=markup), not `httpd.h`.